# How do I make my row names appear on my x axis? And the numbers on from my variables appear as the y axis?

Tags: r, histogram

I created a dataframe with countries as row names and percentages as obs. from the variables, but when making a histogram it seems that the percentages from the variables are occupying the x axis and the country names aren't even there. How do I make it so that the countrie's names are on the x axis and the variables on the y?

```r
Country <- c('Albania','Armenia','Austria','Belarus','Belgium','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Cyprus','Czechia','Denmark','Estonia','Finland','France','Georgia','Germany','Greece','Hungary','Iceland','Ireland','Italy','Latvia','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Malta','Moldova','Montenegro','Netherlands','Norway','Poland','Portugal','Romania','Russia','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Turkey','Ukraine','United Kingdom')
Anxiety.Disorders <- c(3.38,2.73,5.22,3.03,4.92,3.70,3.84,3.74,5.61,3.59,5.18,3.01,3.59,6.37,2.46,6.37,5.58,3.69,5.15,5.66,5.57,3.04,3.06,5.19,5.14,2.77,3.55,6.43,7.33,3.68,5.52,3.41,3.02,3.60,3.61,3.60,5.14,5.16,5.28,3.85,3.09,4.43)
Depressive.Disorders <- c(2.42,3.16,3.66,4.84,4.35,2.88,3.30,3.60,3.88,3.25,3.62,4.78,5.08,4.55,2.98,4.42,4.56,3.53,3.55,4.37,3.94,4.44,5.20,3.95,3.69,3.77,2.96,4.34,3.95,2.72,5.27,2.88,4.36,3.15,2.87,3.58,3.91,4.84,4.17,3.76,5.02,4.35)
Bipolar.Disorder <- c(0.72,0.77,0.95,0.73,0.91,0.79,0.67,0.77,1.04,0.75,0.99,0.71,0.99,0.93,0.67,0.79,0.93,0.74,0.97,0.80,0.95,0.71,0.73,0.95,0.97,0.67,0.74,0.94,0.85,0.76,0.97,0.78,0.70,0.74,0.76,0.75,0.97,1.04,0.98,0.85,0.73,1.05)
G08 <- data.frame(Country, Anxiety.Disorders, Depressive.Disorders, Bipolar.Disorder)
row.names(G08) <- G08$Country
G08[1] <- NULL

hist(G08$Anxiety.Disorders)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want a histogram? Or a grouped column diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the melt() call to create one observation per row. Then, I use ggplot to produce the bar plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

Country <- c('Albania','Armenia','Austria','Belarus','Belgium','Bosnia-Herzegovina','Bulgaria','Croatia','Cyprus','Czechia','Denmark','Estonia','Finland','France','Georgia','Germany','Greece','Hungary','Iceland','Ireland','Italy','Latvia','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Malta','Moldova','Montenegro','Netherlands','Norway','Poland','Portugal','Romania','Russia','Serbia','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Turkey','Ukraine','United Kingdom')

Anxiety.Disorders <- c(3.38,2.73,5.22,3.03,4.92,3.70,3.84,3.74,5.61,3.59,5.18,3.01,3.59,6.37,2.46,6.37,5.58,3.69,5.15,5.66,5.57,3.04,3.06,5.19,5.14,2.77,3.55,6.43,7.33,3.68,5.52,3.41,3.02,3.60,3.61,3.60,5.14,5.16,5.28,3.85,3.09,4.43)

Depressive.Disorders <- c(2.42,3.16,3.66,4.84,4.35,2.88,3.30,3.60,3.88,3.25,3.62,4.78,5.08,4.55,2.98,4.42,4.56,3.53,3.55,4.37,3.94,4.44,5.20,3.95,3.69,3.77,2.96,4.34,3.95,2.72,5.27,2.88,4.36,3.15,2.87,3.58,3.91,4.84,4.17,3.76,5.02,4.35)

Bipolar.Disorder <- c(0.72,0.77,0.95,0.73,0.91,0.79,0.67,0.77,1.04,0.75,0.99,0.71,0.99,0.93,0.67,0.79,0.93,0.74,0.97,0.80,0.95,0.71,0.73,0.95,0.97,0.67,0.74,0.94,0.85,0.76,0.97,0.78,0.70,0.74,0.76,0.75,0.97,1.04,0.98,0.85,0.73,1.05)

G08 <- data.frame(Country, Anxiety.Disorders, Depressive.Disorders, Bipolar.Disorder)

G08melt <- melt(G08, "Country")

G08.bar <- ggplot(G08melt, aes(x = Country, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),stat="identity", position ="dodge") + 
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-40, hjust=.1))

G08.bar
```

[image]

Comment: Some notes: (1) This is a bar-plot, not a histogram. (2) You should probably mention that you are using `G08` *before* the OP removes the `$Country` column, since your `melt` requires it. (3) If you're already loading the gazillion packages within `tidyverse`, why not use `pivot_longer`? There is nothing that `melt` can do that it cannot, and it is (subjectively) far more intuitive and usable. (4) Further, `reshape` hasn't been updated in over 2.5 years ... while Hadley's work does tend to persist well, there are many good alternatives (e.g., `reshape2` and `tidyr`).

Comment: And (5) you should really include the plot that this code generates, it is immediately useful and elegant as a replacement for the OP's first attempt. Show it off, it's good. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I think you tried to do a grouped column diagram instead of a histogram. You can do the plot directly using the `barplot` function from the `graphics` package. But before that, you need to convert your `dataframe` into a `matrix`. I removed the first column from `G08`.

```
mat<-G08[,-1]
```

Now just simply use the `barplot` function on the transpose of the matrix `mat` and use the `names` parameter of `barplot` to write the names of the Countries on the x-axis:

```
barplot(t(mat),beside=T,col=c('red','blue','gold'),border=NA,names=G08$Country,cex.names=0.45,las=2)
par(new=T)
legend('topright',c("Anxiety","Depressive","Bipolar"),fill=c("red","blue","gold"),cex=0.5,title='Disorder types')
```

[image: Graph-1]

---

**Suggestion:**
For a little bit of more 'fresh air' in the graph, you can just set `beside=F` in `barplot` and get a stacked column diagram:

[image: Graph-2]